# How do you visualize neural network architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, visualization

When writing a paper / making a presentation about a topic which is about neural networks, one usually visualizes the networks architecture.

What are good / simple ways to visualize common architectures automatically?

Comment: See also: [How can a neural network architecture be visualized with Keras?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38442107/562769)

Comment: Just found https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4sgsn9/drawing_cnn_architectures/

Comment: I wrote [Simple diagrams of convoluted neural networks](https://medium.com/inbrowserai/simple-diagrams-of-convoluted-neural-networks-39c097d2925b) with a survey of deep learning visualization approaches (both manual and automatic). I got a lot of inspiration, and links, from this thread - thx!

Answer (score 92):

I recently created a tool for drawing NN architectures and exporting SVG, called [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html)

[image]

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: Download SVG doesn't work

Comment: works for me 1/23/19. If you're still having an issue, please feel free to open an issue.

Comment: this is the only right answer

Comment: awesome tool. However, I noticed that in AlexNet style, the dimensions of the Tensors were mistakenly represented (width and height dimensions)

Comment: Awesome, how can i visualize LSTM and attention?

Comment: @AlexLenail is this project open source?

Comment: https://github.com/alexlenail/NN-SVG

Comment: Really awesome tool!

Comment: Does it support adding Batchnorm and Dropout layers?

Answer (score 52):

### Tensorflow, Keras, MXNet, PyTorch

If the neural network is given as a Tensorflow graph, then you can [visualize this graph with TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz).

Here is how the MNIST CNN looks like:

[image]

You can add names / scopes (like "dropout", "softmax", "fc1", "conv1", "conv2") yourself.

#### Interpretation

The following is only about the left graph. I ignore the 4 small graphs on the right half.

Each box is a layer with parameters that can be learned. For inference, information flows from bottom to the top. Ellipses are layers which do not contain learned parameters.

The color of the boxes does not have a meaning.

I'm not sure of the value of the dashed small boxes ("gradients", "Adam", "save").

Comment: it is good, I am trying to avoid the name like conv1, conv2 etc, I want to make all the name of conv later as CONV, How I will do??

Comment: +1. It's not only for TF though: [MXNet](https://github.com/awslabs/mxboard) and [Pytorch](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch) have some support too

Comment: @SudipDas You can add names in the code to the layers, which will show up as you plot it.

Comment: How I will show the name of each layer as "CONV", if I write it as "CONV" of each layer then I will get error, cause each layer should have a unique name as tf rules, BUT I want to know, is there any other way to overcome this problem?? @Ben

Comment: @SudipDas Oh well, that does not work. I think you can only overcome this problem by storing it and editing it yourself. Maybe you can cheat by adding invisible characters to the name, but I would recommend giving them unique names anyway.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, Thank you so much for your reply @Ben

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @onof I fixed the link

Comment: The link is dead again.

Answer (score 33):

There is an open source project called [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron)

> Netron is a viewer for neural network, deep learning and machine learning models.
>
> Netron supports ONNX (.onnx, .pb), Keras (.h5, .keras), CoreML (.mlmodel) and TensorFlow Lite (.tflite). Netron has experimental support for Caffe (.caffemodel), Caffe2 (predict_net.pb), MXNet (-symbol.json), TensorFlow.js (model.json, .pb) and TensorFlow (.pb, .meta).

[image]

Answer (score 21):

In Caffe you can use  [caffe/draw.py](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/draw.py) to draw the NetParameter protobuffer:

[image]

In Matlab, you can use  [view(net)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/view.html)

[image]

[Keras.js](https://transcranial.github.io/keras-js/#/inception-v3):

[image]

Also, see [Can anyone recommend a Network Architecture visualization tool? (Reddit/self.MachineLearning)](https://redd.it/kmfx2d).

Answer (score 21):

I would add ASCII visualizations using [keras-sequential-ascii](https://github.com/stared/keras-sequential-ascii) (disclaimer: I am the author).

A small network for CIFAR-10 (from [this tutorial](https://blog.deepsense.ai/deep-learning-hands-on-image-classification/)) would be:

```
       OPERATION           DATA DIMENSIONS   WEIGHTS(N)   WEIGHTS(%)

           Input   #####     32   32    3
          Conv2D    \|/  -------------------       896     2.1%
            relu   #####     30   30   32
    MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                   #####     15   15   32
          Conv2D    \|/  -------------------     18496    43.6%
            relu   #####     13   13   64
    MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                   #####      6    6   64
         Flatten   ||||| -------------------         0     0.0%
                   #####        2304
           Dense   XXXXX -------------------     23050    54.3%
         softmax   #####          10
```

For VGG16 it would be:

```
       OPERATION           DATA DIMENSIONS   WEIGHTS(N)   WEIGHTS(%)

          Input   #####      3  224  224
     InputLayer     |   -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####      3  224  224
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------      1792     0.0%
           relu   #####     64  224  224
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------     36928     0.0%
           relu   #####     64  224  224
   MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####     64  112  112
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------     73856     0.1%
           relu   #####    128  112  112
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------    147584     0.1%
           relu   #####    128  112  112
   MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####    128   56   56
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------    295168     0.2%
           relu   #####    256   56   56
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------    590080     0.4%
           relu   #####    256   56   56
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------    590080     0.4%
           relu   #####    256   56   56
   MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####    256   28   28
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   1180160     0.9%
           relu   #####    512   28   28
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   2359808     1.7%
           relu   #####    512   28   28
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   2359808     1.7%
           relu   #####    512   28   28
   MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####    512   14   14
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   2359808     1.7%
           relu   #####    512   14   14
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   2359808     1.7%
           relu   #####    512   14   14
  Convolution2D    \|/  -------------------   2359808     1.7%
           relu   #####    512   14   14
   MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####    512    7    7
        Flatten   ||||| -------------------         0     0.0%
                  #####       25088
          Dense   XXXXX ------------------- 102764544    74.3%
           relu   #####        4096
          Dense   XXXXX -------------------  16781312    12.1%
           relu   #####        4096
          Dense   XXXXX -------------------   4097000     3.0%
        softmax   #####        1000
```

Answer (score 18):

**Keras**

The [keras.utils.vis_utils module](https://keras.io/visualization/) provides utility functions to plot a Keras model (using graphviz)

The following shows a network model that the first hidden layer has 50 neurons and expects 104 input variables.

```
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use it in LaTex compatible format?

Comment: they use it so obviously you can.. probably just embed the image like any other figure

Answer (score 13):

Here is yet another way - [dotnets](https://github.com/martisak/dotnets), using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), heavily inspired by [this post](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/draw-neural-network-diagrams-graphviz/) by Thiago G. Martins.

[image: dotnets example]

Answer (score 13):

I've been working on a drag-and-drop neural network visualizer (and more). Here's an example of a visualization for a LeNet-like architecture. [image: A visualization of a LeNet-like architecture]
Models with fan-out and fan-in are also quite easily modeled. You can visit the website at https://math.mit.edu/ennui/

The open-source implementation is available at https://github.com/martinjm97/ENNUI.

Comment: my browser keeps crashing when press Train

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. Yes, this bug just popped up recently and seems to be a result of some recent changes to WebGL on Chrome. Everything should work on Firefox. I'll update you when I know more.

Comment: tks, your visualiser is amazing, looks greater than tf playground :)

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if you have issues or ideas. We have fun things like code generation too!

Comment: Bug fixes are in and the implementation has been open-sourced!

Answer (score 13):

## PlotNeuralNet LaTex tool

This solution is not automatically generated (you need to construct the graph by yourself) but [the PlotNeuralNet github repo](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet) allows you to build images directly from LaTex, and the result is great ! See for example the image below from the README :
[image: Example of NN draw with]

or my example :

[image: My own example, without the operations legend (sorry)]

Comment: This is a really good visualization! Does it require the user to have Latex downloaded on the hard drive, or is it possible to this through Overleaf / ShareLatex? I am having some problems getting it to work on Overleaf.

Comment: Hello, They do have examples running on Overleaf in the Readme file of the package. It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 12):

The Python package `conx` can visualize networks with activations with the function `net.picture()` to produce SVG, PNG, or PIL Images like this:

[image]

Conx is built on Keras, and can read in Keras' models. The colormap at each bank can be changed, and it can show all bank types.

More information can be found at: http://conx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 10):

In R, `nnet` does not come with a plot function, but code for that is provided [here](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/visualizing-neural-networks-from-the-nnet-package/).

Alternatively, you can use the more recent and IMHO better package called `neuralnet` which features a `plot.neuralnet` function, so you can just do:

```
data(infert, package="datasets")
plot(neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert))
```

[image: neuralnet]

`neuralnet` is not used as much as `nnet` because `nnet` is much older and is shipped with r-cran. But `neuralnet` has more training algorithms, including [resilient backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop) which is lacking even in packages like Tensorflow, and is much more robust to hyperparameter choices, and has more features overall.

Comment: You should add the updated link for the code of NNet in R https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/visualizing-neural-networks-in-r-update/

Answer (score 7):

There are some novel alternative efforts on neural network visualization.

Please see these articles:

[Stunning 'AI brain scans' reveal what machines see as they learn new skills](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/ai-machine-learning-brain-scan)

[Inside an AI 'brain' - What does machine learning look like?](https://www.graphcore.ai/posts/what-does-machine-learning-look-like)

These approaches are more oriented towards visualizing neural network operation, however, NN architecture is also somewhat visible on the resulting diagrams.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain what we see here. It looks beautiful, but I don't understand how the fancy images support understanding the operation of the network.

Comment: I don't like your derogatory usage of "fancy images" term. @Martin

Comment: One could call your diagram "lego boxes" as well, and ask the same question. This is not an appropriate conversation style for this site.

Comment: I didn't mean to attack you, but your overly defensive answer without actually answering my question speaks for itself. - I added an "interpretation" part to the "lego boxes" diagram.

Comment: By the way: The second link is dead.

Comment: @MartinThoma It's clearly data art, not data viz (vide https://lisacharlotterost.github.io/2015/12/19/Meaning-and-Beauty-in-Data-Vis/).

Comment: Not sure how is this useful, in fact those labels could be anything.

Comment: To like is one thing, but isn't it accurate to call the images fancy? I think it's an appropriate conversation style if it conveys the intended message, and in this case I guess that was that the images look more interesting than what they are useful. When it comes to the lego boxes (which I think would be a fair description), they communicate certain aspects of the architecture very effectively (number of layers, shape of layers, connections, etc.), which is not something I immediately see in these images. If you become good at interpreting them, it might be another thing, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the popular paper [Understanding Neural Networks Through Deep Visualization](http://yosinski.com/media/papers/Yosinski__2015__ICML_DL__Understanding_Neural_Networks_Through_Deep_Visualization__.pdf) which discusses visualization of convolutional nets. [Its implementation](https://github.com/yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox) not only  displays each layer but also depicts the activations, weights, deconvolutions and many other things that are deeply discussed in the paper. It's code is in `caffe'`. The interesting part is that you can replace the pre-trained model with your own.

Comment: that's about showing **the weights/activations**, not the structure... at least from what I can see in the paper and the repo's readme

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes actually. Most of the other answers are about the structure. Mine is about what you've mentioned. By the way, it was about visualisation of neural nets.

Answer (score 5):

Tensorspace-JS is a fantastic tool for 3d visualization of network architecture:

[image]

https://tensorspace.org/

and here is a nice post about how to write a program:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/tensorspace-js-a-way-to-3d-visualize-neural-networks-in-browsers-2c0afd7648a8

Comment: Could you provide a link to this tool?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Tensorflow / Keras / Python

I wrote a small python package called *visualkeras* that allows you to directly generate the architecture from your keras model.

Install via `pip install visualkeras`

And then it's as simple as:

```
import visualkeras
visualkeras.layered_view(<model>)
```

There are lots of options to tweak it and I am working on more visualizations. Also, always open for PRs or feature requests.

Here's what VGG16 looks like:
[image: VGG16 architecture]

Answer (score 4):

Not per se nifty for papers, but very useful for showing people who don't know a lot of about neural networks what their topology may look like. This [Javascript library (Neataptic)](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) lets you visualise your network:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Netscope](http://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/quickstart.html) is my everyday tool for Caffe models.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found one amazing website. You just need to upload your h5 model, Then you will get a beautiful visualization within a few seconds. [Check it out!](https://netron.app/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, already covered in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/30642/843

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eiffel2`, which you can install using `pip`:

```
python -m pip install eiffel2
```

Just import `builder` from `eiffel` and provide a list of neurons per layer in your network as an input.

Example:

```py
from eiffel2 import builder

builder([1, 10, 10, 5, 5, 2, 1])
# or the following if you want to have a dark theme
builder([1, 10, 10, 5, 5, 2, 1], bmode="night")
```

Output:

[image: Normal output]

[image: output with bmode="night"]

To see more about eiffel2 visit the Github repository:

https://github.com/Ale9806/Eiffel2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I just figured out Eiffel does not have support anymore, use eiffel2 instead

Comment: Session crashed.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution for PyTorch I'd add [TorchView](https://github.com/mert-kurttutan/torchview).

It is as easy as:

```py
from torchview import draw_graph

model = MLP()
batch_size = 2
# device='meta' -> no memory is consumed for visualization
model_graph = draw_graph(model, input_size=(batch_size, 128), device='meta')
model_graph.visual_graph
```

Which yields:

[image]

It has many customization options as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a plug for my recent project, [TorchExplorer](https://github.com/spfrommer/torchexplorer) (live demo [here](https://wandb.ai/spfrom_team/torchexplorer_demo/reports/TorchExplorer-interactive-neural-network-inspection--Vmlldzo1OTUxNDQy)). It's sort of a combination of Netron and wandb.watch. It can:

- Interactively traverse model architectures, showing input/output tensor sizes and module parameters
- Visualize module input/output tensors, parameters, and associated gradients as histograms over the course of training (modeled off of wandb.watch)
- Directly integrate with weights and biases or serve standalone with a simple torchexplorer.watch call

[image]