# How to draw Deep learning network architecture diagrams?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, svm, software-recommendation

I have built my model. Now I want to draw the network architecture diagram for my research paper. Example is shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think graphiz, based on the dot language can, can help you.

Comment: https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet

Comment: If you are using latex, just use tikz. It does require a little time to get used to.

Comment: It seems like the best approach would be to endow the network with the capability for self-reflection, and teach it how to draw its mind. Easy peasy.

Comment: For a tool & approaches overview, see: https://medium.com/inbrowserai/simple-diagrams-of-convoluted-neural-networks-39c097d2925b

Answer (score 144):

I recently found [this online tool](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html) that produces publication-ready NN-architecture schematics. It is called [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html) and made by [Alex Lenail](http://alexlenail.me).

You can easily export these to use in, say, **LaTeX** for example.

Here are a few examples:

*AlexNet style*
[image: AlexNet style]

---

*LeNet style*
[image]

---

and the good old *Fully Connected* style
[image]

Comment: This tool seems great -- however, I noticed that it assumes the inputs are always square. I'm in an application with a rectangular input, so this doesn't quite work.

Comment: The tool now accommodates rectangular inputs, give it a try

Comment: This is great for standard CNN backbones, but in more complex architectures like encoder-decoder, attention, etc. it'd be nice to have the flexibility to re-arrange the rectangular components in any arbitrary layout

Answer (score 90):

I wrote some latex code to draw Deep networks for one of my reports. You can find it here: https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet

With this, you can draw networks like these:
[image]

Comment: Best answer and should be voted up.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is an amazing tool. Wish I had time to utilize this!

Comment: +1. Used it for my bachelor thesis two years ago, I think it is awesome especially for slides.

Answer (score 19):

- For automated drawing, see [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12851/843), https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28169/903 and  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/47841/903
- For manual drawing, see https://redd.it/574usi

Comment: Can VISIO draw these architectures?

Answer (score 8):

[Netron viewer](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/netron) is the best tool to draw your model architecture

[image]

I suppose you have a pretrained model stored in .h5 file.

Comment: Great tool. Thanks for sharing. This works well with MATLAB exported networks as well.

Comment: I love Netron for visualizing and understanding my models, but I don't think it's great for explaining them to others in a paper. The diagram is far too detailed in my opinion to get a high-level overview of the architecture

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: The new link seems to be: https://netron.app

Answer (score 6):

[image: Model Architecture]

I drew this with [draw.io](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drawio-desktop/pebppomjfocnoigkeepgbmcifnnlndla?hl=en-GB), you can also choose other structures of the drawing e.g circles.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Powerpoint to get the job done.

Draw the diagram (3D rectangles and perspectives come handy) -> select the interested area on the slide -> right-click -> Save as picture -> change filetype to PDF -> :)