# How to draw convolutional neural network diagrams?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have to draw a CNN diagram similar to this:
[image]

I tried all the tools mentioned in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/14900, but there is no easy way to do it.
Is there any automated way to do it? Or do I have to do it manually.

In addition, is it possible to draw this?:
[image]

I found http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html, however, in this the input to each layer is assumed to be a perfect square. Thus, I cannot draw above diagram.

Answer (score 6):

As to your first example most full featured drawing software should be capable of manually drawing almost anything including that diagram.

For example, the webpage "[The Neural Network Zoo](http://www.asimovinstitute.org/neural-network-zoo/)" has a cheat sheet containing many neural network architectures. It might provide some examples. The author's webpage says:

> Djeb - Sep 15, 2016
>
> Amazing. What software did you used to plot these figures ? Cheers !
>
> Fjodor van Veen - Sep 15, 2016
>
> **I drew them in Adobe Animate**, they’re not plots. Yes it was a lot of work to draw the lines.
>
> Garrett Smith - Sep 15, 2016
>
> Are your excellent images available for reuse under a particular license? Do you have an attribution policy?
>
> Fjodor van Veen - Sep 16, 2016
>
> As long as you mention the author and link to the Asimov Institute, use them however and wherever you like!

[image: Neural Network Zoo Architectures]

As for general automated plotting a commonly used package for Python is [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), more specific to AI, programs like [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs) use a [dataflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming) graph to represent your computation in terms of the dependencies between individual operations.

TensorFlow computation graphs are powerful but complicated. The [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz) graph visualization can help you understand and debug them. Here's an example of the visualization.

[image: TensorFlow Graph Visualization]

A combination of automated output and manually annotating some of the details can produce sophisticated images not available from any one program.

This [search turns up 1000's of diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22convolutional%20layer%22%20%22max-pooling%22%20%22fully%20connected%22%20%22output%20layer%22%20matplotlib&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFsIqLgYrdAhVPHjQIHQI-BxwQ_AUICigB&biw=980&bih=1666&dpr=4) from which you can obtain ideas to model your own images.