# How to draw neural network diagrams with this particular style?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, recommender-system, software-recommendation

I would like to draw a neural network architecture with the follow style. Do you know which tool can be used to do this? The paper is [Operation-aware Neural Networks for User Response Prediction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12579).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked me something similar as well as I thought that a lot of papers use rather high quality images but it seems that all the authors generate them individually: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114886/software-to-draw-schemes-quickly
For NNs, there is already an answered question: [How to draw Deep learning network architecture diagrams?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14899/how-to-draw-deep-learning-network-architecture-diagrams)
Have a look at https://www.quora.com/What-tools-are-good-for-drawing-neural-network-architecture-diagrams and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47841/drawing-neural-networks

Comment: I'm using yEd. It works well on this task.